# Get original file name + line number in exceptions thrown in Angular controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have an error in an Angular controller, I get a stack trace which looks something like this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (…/dist/script.js:854:5)
    at invoke (…/dist/base-script.js:13441:17)
    at Object.instantiate (…/dist/base-script.js:13452:23)
    at …/dist/base-script.js:16789:28
    at …/dist/base-script.js:16159:34
    at forEach (…/dist/base-script.js:9709:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (…/dist/base-script.js:16146:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (…/dist/base-script.js:15582:13)
    at publicLinkFn (…/dist/base-script.js:15477:30)
    at link (…/dist/base-script.js:30282:38) <div ng-include="activeTab" class="ng-scope">
```

Where `script.js` and `script-base.js` are minified scripts.

How can I figure out which real line of source code is causing the problem?

Note that I am compiling source maps and they are working correctly when a "native" error is thrown (ie, Chrome can correctly show me original source lines when Angular does *not* intercept errors).

Comment: Ugh...Angular errors are terrible when they happen in a minified state...best guess is always an injector error - doesn't seem that way though from this error. Since this doesnt happen unminified I'm guessing your syntax isn't minification safe. Can you post how you declare your Angular controllers/directives/modules?

Comment: @tymeJV I'm asking specifically how I can debug this error in the general case. I'd like a general method for figuring out which source line caused an error.

Comment: Gotcha... either way - you could find a JS beautifier and insert the minified / uglified JS into that and go from there, other than that I dont think there's an easy way, AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Chrome limitation:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357958
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=222270

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible to override `$exceptionHandler` with a function that re-throws errors:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function($log) {
  return function (exception, cause) {
    if (cause) {
      $log.error('exception cause:', cause);
    }
    throw exception;
  };
});
```

This may have other unintended consequences, but it certainly makes debugging easier.